# Empty web application posts back on Enter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've created a new web application, and removed all server controls. I then implemented a google map and searchbox from this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Practically just copy-pasted the code.

Everything works fine like in the Google example, but the problem is that when I search and press Enter, the page posts back and thus reloads the page as new.. I can't find out what triggers reloading the page.

Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Vegindex.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/map.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site.Master.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Vegindex
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vegindex._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        initialize(); // here is the Google code 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Vegindex
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The default behaviour of a form element is to submit on enter event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the default behaviour, you need to specify a default button.

Modify your form tag in your Master Page like this:

```
<form runat="server" defaultbutton="btnDisableEnter">
```

and add the according button to the bottom of your Master Page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDisableEnter" runat="server" Text="" OnClientClick="return false;" style="display:none;" />
```

**Disclaimer:**

Solution adopted from [ASP.NET: Disable Submit Form on Enter Key](http://weblog.kevinattard.com/2011/08/aspnet-disable-submit-form-on-enter-key.html)

Comment: Thanks @Filburt, I'll be removing the `form` tag all together because I'm actually not going to use server code at the moment but would like to perserve the option for the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnStopEnter" runat="server"  style="display:none" OnClientClick="javascript:return StopEnter();"  />
```

in java script

```
function StopEnter(){
return false;
}
```

In C# you can set default button

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form.DefaultButton = btnStopEnter.UniqueID;
}
```